# different between a + 1 + 1 and a + 2 in python

Tags: python

I recently encountered a problem:

```
a = 0.0001
b1 = a + 1 + 1
b2 = a + 2
b2 = a + 2
c1 = str(int(b1-a))
c2 = str(int(b2-a))
```

the result:

c1=1,
c2=2

why? who can help me?

Comment: Look at the values of `b1` and `b2` and you'll figure it out quickly.

Comment: In python execution starts from left to right and when it comes to arithmetic it follows bod mas rule.